# Web Page Parsing - WP8 - HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, parsing, windows-phone-8, html-agility-pack

I am actually trying to parse the content of this webpage, http://www.cryptocoincharts.info/v2/coins/show/tips

In particular I'd need to get the numbers, like "Current Difficulty", "Mined coins till now" etc

I am not actually sure how to do that, I actually located the section where my numbers are, yet I am not able to write the code to actually get those numbers out :(

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: This is the code I have so far:

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            string htmlPage = "";
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    htmlPage = await client.GetStringAsync("http://www.cryptocoincharts.info/v2/coins/show/tips");
                }
                catch (HttpRequestException exc) { }
            }

        HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(htmlPage);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you read any tutorials or examples?

Comment: Of course I did, http://www.tareqateik.com/html-agility-pack%E2%80%93windows-phone-8#.UxCyPrG8_q5
I followed this tutorial, I can't understand the logic behind this:

Comment: List<Movie> movies = new List<Movie>();
            foreach (var div in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[starts-with(@class, 'list_item')]"))
            {
                Movie newMovie = new Movie();
                newMovie.Cover = div.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='image']//img").Attributes["src"].Value;
                newMovie.Title = div.SelectSingleNode(".//h4[@itemprop='name']").InnerText.Trim();
                newMovie.Summary = div.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='outline']").InnerText.Trim();
                movies.Add(newMovie);
            }

Comment: Where is the code for the actual selection of Nodes (`SelectNodes`)? It's using XPath query syntax mostly. I'm reluctant to show you if you don't have permission to scrape the contents of that web page. The tutorial you linked has some sophisticated examples.

Comment: I am actually not sure on how to set up the selection of nodes.
I am trying to understand how to do that, the page actually has nothing to do with any work, I am just studying that page cause it looked quite simple to work on, but I suppose I was wrong :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
var html = await client.GetStringAsync("http://www.cryptocoincharts.info/v2/coins/show/tips");
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var result = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='table table-striped']")
                .Descendants("tr")
                .Skip(1)
                .Select(tr => new
                {
                    Desc = tr.SelectSingleNode("td[1]").InnerText,
                    Val = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(tr.SelectSingleNode("td[2]").InnerText)
                })
                .ToList();
```