# How to display html content as Textblock text in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, html, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am developing a Windows Phone 8 application. In this application I am getting some HTML content, This HTML content I have to display on the screen without tags, but it should display the text decorations like bold, hyperlinks and all.

How to achieve this? Please share your views

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get body details like this. after that you can bind to Text-block Control

```
 HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 doc.Load("mypage.htm");

 HtmlNode Bodycontent= doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body");

 if(Bodycontent!= null)
 {
    // do something
 }
```

[HTML parsing and validation with HtmlAgilityPack](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshch/archive/2006/12/10/better-html-parsing-and-validation-with-htmlagilitypack.aspx)

Comment: HtmlDocument is not dere in windows phone 8. Shall i have to add some nuget or external dll?

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack 1.4.9 : Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack

Comment: I added the package and reference too. suppose i have html content like this........    <h1>hi gud mrng!</h1><b>How r u?</b><a href="www.google.com"></a>............. then how to get content and display in same format like How r u? to be bold and so on in the textblock

Comment: See here for more info   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22103379/web-page-parsing-wp8-htmlagilitypack